# How to change elements opacity based on if checkbox is or is not checked with CSS only?

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox, checked

I know that I could use `.is(':checked')` with jQuery, but is there a CSS way? I kind of would like to make this `#navbar-checkbox:checked #mobile-nav { display: block; }` bit of code work, as I know I could do something similar with `:hover`, but is there a way to do it with `:checked` ?

So the full markup:

**CSS**

```
#mobile-nav { display: none; }
#navbar-checkbox:checked #mobile-nav { display: block; }
```

That's really all I want.

Comment: It is possible but the real markup is required.

Comment: You need to replace your descendant combinator with one that describes the relationship between the two elements. There is no way that any element is going to be a descendant of a checkbox (because input elements can't have child nodes).

Comment: By *markup* I meant your current HTML.

Comment: "So the full markup" — There isn't any markup there. The markup is your HTML, not your CSS.

Comment: if they are siblings then http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/h8s5bv1g/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be helpful to see your markup, but it is possible.

For example, this assumes a checkbox that is [*adjacent*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) (specified by the `+` combinator) to the element you want to target:

```css
.test {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .test { opacity: 0.5; }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
<div class="test">Test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#myDIv {
  display: none;
}
.myDiv input:checked + #myDIv {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
  <input id="navbarcheckbox" type="checkbox" name="option" value="Test">
  <div id="myDIv">
    <span>Hello</span>
    <span>World!</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How is it different than [@AndréDion](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1503994/andr%c3%a9-dion)'s [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29367307/1725764)?

Comment: Not different, I was writing the snippet when he posted.. Im not superman